# Cleaner way for changing button's text color on signal pressed & released

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals

In my pyqt gui while a button is pressed the button's text color changes. And when the button is released the color goes back to its original self.

I have the code working like the following:

```
    self.ui.pButton_save.pressed.connect(self.save_pressed)
    self.ui.pButton_cancel.pressed.connect(self.cancel_pressed)
    self.ui.pButton_save.released.connect(self.save_released)
    self.ui.pButton_cancel.released.connect(self.cancel_released)

def save_pressed(self):
    self.ui.pButton_save.setStyleSheet("color: white")

def cancel_pressed(self):
    self.ui.pButton_cancel.setStyleSheet("color: white")

def save_released(self):
    self.ui.pButton_save.setStyleSheet("color: green")

def cancel_released(self):
    self.ui.pButton_cancel.setStyleSheet("color: red")
```

The code works fine. But as you can see there are so many lines for this simple task. Probably there is a cleaner (more Pythonic) way of doing it. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to do it with Qt Style Sheet, the ones that handle the states like the pressed button.

```
self.ui.pButton_save.setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton:pressed{color: white} QPushButton{color: green}")
self.ui.pButton_cancel.setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton:pressed{color: white} QPushButton{color: red}")
```

Comment: Excellent! This was exactly what I was looking for. @eyllanesc Thank you!